# Using C++17 'any' with Xcode 8.1

Tags: c++, c++17, stdany

I am using C++ in Xcode version 8.1.  I need to use the functionality of `boost::any` but am strongly opposed to pulling any part of Boost into our project (let's not debate it please).

I see that `std::any` is "merged into C++17" [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/lib_extensions).

I want to use this in my Xcode 8.1 project.  I have tried using `-std=c++1z` as a custom flag on the project, but I can't seem to find a header for it.

How can I use `std::any` or `std::experimental::any` in my Xcode project?

Can I download the appropriate headers from an implementation and throw them into my project's sourcecode?  Or, even better, is actually available to now in my version of Xcode/Clang/C++?

Comment: Xcode is an IDE.   It comes with a compiler, but you are not required to use that compiler.

Comment: I understand that, but I want to use the vanilla Xcode 8.1 installation and it's default compiler.  Xcode is also not a C++ implementation, I understand that too.  I want to use the C++ implementations that are available to me as an Xcode user by default.

Comment: I am strongly opposed to answering this question (let's not debate it please). No, you can't just "throw them into [your] project's sourcecode". You are going out of your way to make life as complicated and difficult for yourself as possible. I will not support that.

Comment: default clang compiler in xcode doesn't support c++17 yet, nor its experimental extensions.

Comment: So can I obtain some subset of the experimental implementations and include them in my sourcecode?

Comment: Yes, you can. That is what `boost::any` is.

Comment: Well for now I guess I have no choice.  bcp gave me 777 header files to include when I asked for any.hpp.  we hates it.

Comment: I can understand why the desire not to include any part of Boost. But, well, lets not debate it. Not need to feel so strong about this issue. As to the question. C++17 support in Xcode 8.1 clang is unfortunately not very good. Some library features are available in experimental. For example `<experimental/optional>`. Apple stopped reporting which version of LLVM it is based on long ago. But if I have to guess, I would say LLVM release 3.7, bases on the `_LIB_CPP` macro

Comment: I'm joking around a bit, I don't actually have "strong feelings".  If I was going to use boost::any I would just do it (in fact I'm in the process of doing so now), but the point of the question is "can I do it without boost" without getting into "why not boost?"  Don't worry I'm not crying or eating a pint of ice cream over it and I appreciate the help.

Comment: @MatthewJamesBriggs I did not mean *you* feel too strong about. I meant no need to "strongly opposed to answering". If you really don't like the 777 header files, and `any` is only part you need from Boost, one way is to write your in-house version. Sometime it might be worth the effort. You can look into libstdc++, libc++, or Boost's implementation for inspirations. I used to maintain a subset of type_traits in my library for the same reason a few years ago. It's not that bad. However, only you and your team can decide the trade-off

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't say "I want the default Xcode compiler [which has no support for `any`]" and at the same time request it to support `any`. You also can't mix standard library headers for different compiler versions.

You can either

- use a compiler version that provides `std::any` or
- use any third party library that provides another `any`-like type.

Answer (score 2):

Your installation setup does not have the c++17 standard. `std::any` simply is not available to you unless you get a compiler with at least experimental support for what you want.

[Clang Cxx Status](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html)

You'd have a lot better luck just using `boost::any` probably.

If you're really set on not bringing a third party library into play, the reality is that creating your own `any` isn't that difficult. I don't recommend reinventing the wheel but in this case it's not that difficult.

[Here's a SO question with an answer showing a way to do 'any'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988939/how-do-boostvariant-and-boostany-work).

Answer (score 2):

It is illegal to inject new types into `std` via a third party library.  You can upgrade your compiler, get a distinct std library your compiler supports, or use a 3rd party library that provides `any` in another namespace, or write your own.

The first you said no to.

The second is hard, as xcode does not advertise what its compiler actually is.  There are generally two common std libraries that work with clang-llvm derived compilers; libc++ and libstdc++.  That kind of swap tends to be very expensive even if the other one has the feature you want.

The third is basically "use `boost`" or equivalent.

The last isn't hard; a few days work (mostly bugs after the fact), based on writing types of similar complexity, assuming "good enough" is good enough (ie, not getting caught up in ideal exception guarantees, or matching standard exactly, etc).  An implementation will require hyperbolic effort to approach perfection, naturally.

Answer (score 2):

Xcode 9.0 beta can now be downloaded (https://developer.apple.com/download/). It supports the c++17 flag option.

Edit: Xcode 9.2 is publically available with std::any support.

Comment: @Zammbi any link you can provide

Comment: You have to login into Apple Developer: https://developer.apple.com/download/ Currently it is in beta 5. So shouldn't be too long before they release the final version.