# Overload function with different arguments

Tags: c++, polymorphism, hierarchy

Hope you can help me out with this. Consider the following class hierarchy:

```
class Collider
{
  public:
  ... //Some functions that aren't worth mentioning. They all are abstract so the class is abstract.
}

class CircleCollider : public Collider
{
  private:
  vec2 pos_;
  float radius_;

  public:
  ... //The definition of the parent functions and constructor / destructor.
}

class RectCollider : public Collider
{
  private:
  vec2 pos_;
  vec2 size_;

  public:
  ... // Again, the definition of the parent functions and constructor / destructor.
}
```

In another class I've got a pointer to the parent class that creates a new instance of one of the two child classes, depending on an enum value, like so:

```
void SetCollisionType(ECollisionType Type)
{
  switch(Type)
  {
    case CIRCLE:
    {
       Collider* collider = new CircleCollider(pos, radius);
       break;
    }
    case RECTANGLE:
    { 
       Collider* collider = new RectCollider(pos, size);
       break;
    }
  }
}
```

Please note I've simplified the function so you get an idea of how my code works. Now what I want to do is a function that updates the member variables of each Child class, `radius` for `CircleCollider`, and `size` for `RectCollider`. I thought of adding a function to the Collider class:

`virtual void UpdateCollider(float NewRadius, vec2 NewSize) = 0;`

And then define it in each child class.

```
   void CircleCollider::UpdateCollider(float NewRadius, vec2 NewSize)
   { 
     radius_ = NewRadius;
   }

   void RectCollider::UpdateCollider(float NewRadius, vec2 NewSize)
   {
     size_ = NewSize;
   }
```

The problem I see with this is that the definition used in `CircleCollider` will not use the `NewSize` parameter, and the same will happen to `NewRadius` with the definition in `RectCollider`. However, I cannot think of another way to do it. Do you know another way to do it making use of the hierarchy and polymorphism present in this code? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: It depends really on how you call the method. Are the two different arguments somewhat related? Maybe radius is the euclidean length of size? The caller should either know which of the colliders it operates on or it should use the same input for both from which it computes the two different arguments. In the latter case you should be able to move this computation in the collider.

Comment: Note: anything like `{
       Collider* collider = new CircleCollider(pos, radius);
   }` is almost certain to create a memory leak, as `collider` goes out of scope almost instantly. Hopefully this part has been simplified and is not actually in your code.

Comment: @Chipster oh sure! actually collider is a member variable of my class "Sprite". I just wanted to show the variable type in case of any doubt ^^ thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant), if you have access to C++17 or later.

Of course, a poor man's `std::variant` [would probably be a union](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58883468/10957435):

```
union UpdateArg {
    float NewRadius;
    vec2 NewSize;
};
//...
void RectCollider::UpdateCollider(UpdateArg NewSize) {
    //...
}
```

Of course, if you really want to make it extendable for other things, not just circles and rectangles, you also have [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any).

Comment: I haven't used unions yet, so I don't know how they work :S Anyway thanks for your help! I'll take a look at them :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use a base class function accepting a pointer to Collider as an input parameter. Then use dynamic_cast to determine the type of the Collider object and update the parameter accordingly.

Something like this,

```
void Collider::UpdateCollider(Collider *p, float NewRadius, vector NewSize)
{
    if(CircleCollider *p_circle_collider = dynamic_cast<CircleCollider *>(p))
    {
        // this is a CircleCollider object
        p_circle_collider->radius_ = NewRadius;
    }
    else if( RectCollider *p_rect_collider = dynamic_cast<RectCollider *>(p))
    {
        // this is a RectCollider object
        p_rect_collider->size_ = NewSize;
    }
}
```

Of course, you'll need some accessor for radius_ and size_ to compile, or else you need them as public members.

Answer (score 1):

When you have classes that need very different kinds of data to construct and update, the only thing that can be commonly used to construct and update objects of those types is a `std::string` or a stream-like object. That will allow you the generality that can be supported at the base class and the specificity needed by the derived classes.

```
void SetCollisionType(ECollisionType Type,
                      std::istream& is)
{
  switch(Type)
  {
    case CIRCLE:
    {
       float radius;
       is >> radius;
       Collider* collider = new CircleCollider(pos, radius);
       break;
    }
    case RECTANGLE:
    { 
       vec2 size;
       // Assuming such an overload exists.
       is >> size;
       Collider* collider = new RectCollider(pos, size);
       break;
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
void CircleCollider::UpdateCollider(std::istream& is)
{ 
   is >> radius_;
}

void RectCollider::UpdateCollider(std::istream& is)
{
   is >> size_;
}
```

It's easy to construct a `std::istringstream` from a `std::string` and pass them to the above functions.

Comment: How is that performance-wise? Intuitively, passing some floating points should much faster then constructing strings, stringstreams and extracting numbers again.

Comment: @n314159, it'll be terrible in a tight loop. It won't be any issue otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Although the other answers address ways that this *could* work, I would be inclined to take a step back and consider your abstractions. From a design perspective, if you find yourself in a situation where parameters are only orthogonal for different implementations, then you may not have chosen an effective abstraction from the start.

You should consider whether the `UpdateCollider` needs to be virtual at all. Judging by the enum of `ECollisionType`, this appears to be a fixed number of types. In which case, you could re-design your `Collider` implementations such that each of them have public member functions that satisfy their goals, e.g.:

```cpp
class CircleCollider : public Collider
{
private:
   // ...

public:
   void setRadius(...);
}

class RectCollider : public Collider
{
private:
  // ..

public:
  void setSize(...);
}
```

And then, rather than updating in some `Collider::UpdateCollider` abstract function, you can do the update from outside (such as in some `ColliderManager`) by casting to the correct underlying type, and calling the specific setters required for that type. There are two possible ways I can think of to do this:

- using `dynamic_cast` to poll for the correct type (creates an `if`/`else if` ladder)
- using your `ECollisionType` to designate a program invariant, which assumes that `ECollisionType` is always accurately specifying the correct `Collider` type -- then using `static_cast` to the correct type (note: This is technically less-safe if ever your invariant isn't upheld, since it could lead to Undefined Behavior -- but would be faster since it doesn't require querying RTTI).

For example:

```cpp
// Using dynamic_cast
void ColliderManager::dynamicColliderUpdater(Collider& c) {
  if (auto* p = dynamic_cast<CircleCollider&>(&c) {
    p->setRadius(...);
  } else if (auto* p = dynamic_cast<RectCollider&>(&c) {
    p->setSize(...);
  } 
  ...
}

// Using static cast
void ColliderManager::staticColliderUpdater(Collider& c, EColliderType t)
{
  switch (t) {
    case CIRCLE: {
      static_cast<CircleCollider&>(c).setRadius(...);
    }
    case RECTANGLE: {
      static_cast<RectCollider&>(c).setSize(...);
    }
    ...
  }

}
```

---

Whether this approach works or not would depend entirely on your design. If you intend to allow consumers to extend and add `Collider` types, then this likely isn't an effective approach. However if it's always fixed and internalized, then a good abstraction is to have a `*Manager` (such as `ColliderManager`) take care of this. The concern of the manager would be updating, and managing all possible collider types -- which doesn't violate any abstraction by having it be aware of the appropriate underlying type. This approach can also allow more complex setters for more complex colliders, and the `ColliderManager` would be responsible for massaging the data so that it coherently works for the respective `Collider`